# Maven exec plugin skip parameter

Tags: maven, gruntjs, maven-plugin, pom.xml, exec-maven-plugin

I have maven exec plugin in my pom for executing grunt. Is there a way to skip the plugin execution when I call mvn clean install. I cant put the `<skip>true</skip` in configuration. I am looking for an option like mvn clean install -Dexec.skip=true. Any clue?

Comment: Have you checked the docs of exec-maven-plugin ?

Comment: I went through the docs. To skip the execution, I can only see the option to change the configuration in the pom.xml by adding <skip>true</skip>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Than you didn't read the [docs well](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html#skip), cause there are the following information:

Excerpt from the docs:

> skip:
>
> Skip the execution.
>
> - Type: boolean
> - Since: 1.0.1
> - Required: No
> - User Property: skip
> - Default: false

The entry `User Property: skip` will guide you to use the following:

```
mvn -Dskip=true ....
```

Comment: clean package  -Dmaven.test.skip=true -Dskip=true is not skipping the maven exec plugin execution. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Which version do of exec-maven-plugin do you use?

Comment: Can put an test project which does not work as expected on github so i can take a look into it?